# Name all grouped variables in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pd.DataFrame, then I make `.groupby(['score group', 'Modality']` and I get the result:
[image]

I need to give a common name for index, to get:
[image]

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Sample data for solve this problem by groupby

Groupby:-

1:-Group the data in for sum function or count function and agg

data.groupby(["id","price"]).sum()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loW8d.png)

[enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)